# How to access an object's attribute if I have the name of the object as a string and the attribute in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.attr = request*3
obj = Test(3)
obj_str = 'obj'
print(obj_str.attr)
```

Above is an example code.
I would like to get obj.attr using the str of obj.
Thank you!

Comment: `globals()[obj_str].attr`?

Comment: It's very unusual to have this need in the first place. You should likely be storing the `obj` object in a dictionary, then you can easily do lookups without resorting to dirty workarounds like using `globals`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyttorak!